# Highcharts loading data from a table generated by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

OK So I have an ajax function that outputs the following html table onto the page after clicking the submit button on a form:

```
<table id="assetAllocation">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Protector</th>
            <th>Balanced</th>
            <th>Progressive</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Cash</th>
            <td>15.69</td>
            <td>18.43</td>
            <td>15.40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Equities</th>
            <td>30.54</td>
            <td>43.18</td>
            <td>54.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Fixed Income</th>
            <td>23.31</td>
            <td>14.49</td>
            <td>8.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Hedge Fund</th>
            <td>0.40</td>
            <td>4.94</td>
            <td>4.98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Commodities</th>
            <td>2.36</td>
            <td>3.73</td>
            <td>3.56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="theading">Other</th>
            <td>27.70</td>
            <td>15.22</td>
            <td>13.16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have the following highcharts function that I just defined at the bottom of the page:

```
function assetChart() {
    $('#assetChart').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('assetAllocation')
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.y +' '+ this.x.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In addition I have the this html as part of the static html of the page:

```
<a href="#" id="clicker">Click me</a>
<div id="assetChart"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#clicker').click(function(){assetChart()});
});
</script>
```

The idea is that once the AJAX-loaded table is generated above I can click the "click me" link and the data will appear in a chart in the `assetChart` container. However this is not working. Nothing actually happens - there are no javascript errors logged. Does `getElementById` work for selecting AJAX-generated content? Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a foolish error of neglecting to include the highcharts data module. Having included it my code now works.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle here to show you how to get this working: http://jsfiddle.net/kQGFt/3/. Basically, run your JS after the DOM is ready. Use the `.on()` method for event delegation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(document).on('click', '#clicker', function(){
        assetChart();
    });
});
```

EDIT: fiddle now fully functional.